# Сырник или творожник?

Tags: словообразование, этимология

"Сир" — по-украински "творог". Отсюда название котлеток из творога — сырники. Но есть ли слово "сырник" в русском языке? Или все-таки "творожник"?

Comment: Сир по украински - сыр. Но и творог тоже. В наших локальных диалектах такое тоже встречается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне себе "сырник". Этимология слова указана верно. Я сам долго удивлялся где же "сыр" в "сырниках". Касательно названия "творожник" - допускаю, что оно существует (тем более, что гуглится), но почему-то ассоциация у меня на него такая, что он представляет собой пирог из творога, а не "сырники"

Comment: >ТВОРОЖНИК Жареная лепёшка из творожной массы с мукой; сырник. Горячий т. Творожники с изюмом. Полить творожники сметаной.  
  
БТС Кузнецова

Answer (score 1):

Сырник и творожник в русском равноправны.
обсуждалось уже. Сейчас попробую найти.
почему-то не могу найти ((((
Может, не здесь обсуждалось...

Comment: Здесь не обсуждалось точно.

Comment: Не столько про сырники, сколько про творог и сыр было как-то здесь обсуждение.  
Может быть **эта** тема?  
[Правильное ударение: "творОг", "твОрог"][1]


  [1]: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8412/правильное-ударение-творог-творог

Comment: >Может быть эта тема? 
  
Бог его знает, может и это,а я действительно сильно попутал с предметом обсуждения. Но скорее всего просто "перенес" сюда то, что было где-то еще. Просто я, вроде, довольно подробно расписывал там детали, а в "твороге" я такого не вижу, только упоминание вскользь.

Answer (score 1):

Сыр и творог вообще разные продукты по технологии изготовления и это заложено в их названии. Все смешалось в доме "Облонских".
Сыр делают естественным свертыванием, потом выдерживают остаток для стекания сыворотки--от сыра-водки-воды. см белорусский словарь.
Теперь так называют настоящий творог, который пластами, и продают на рынках, он кисловатый и с него частенько течет сыворотка.
после высаливания получают сыр-брынзу и другие мягкие сыры.

Творог творят, а точнее варят. Процесс свертывания прекращается пастеризацией.
потом выдержка для стекания.Получается комковатая масса, с минимальной жирностью, поскольку все делается в горячем виде.затем по желанию добавляют сливочное масло, выдерживают, при этом возобновляется процесс брожения(от масла, но и не совсем не как в молоке, другие бактерии тоже попадают из масла в основном долгого хранения, плюс грибки, плесени--получатся сыр типа рокфор) от этого в продукте дырки.
вот это и называют сегодня сыром.

Путаница эта вполне понятна, так как горожанам плевать на технологию.
Сыр достаточно дорогой продукт, пища богатых в достопямятные времена.
Кстати, сыр  в некоторых странах называют OST, восток дело тонкое,
по корням и их остаткам можно определить откуда вообще в Европу пришла технология изготовления обоих продуктов.

Comment: Вы хоть знаете, что по-украински творог - сир (сыр)?
Какая уж тут "технология".)))

Comment: А по-болгарски  сыр-сирене 
  творог - извара
Мелочь. значения не имеет, ерунда это все...технология, а бензин прямо из скважины качают,